# how to implement all java class with Serializable in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a Nebeans project and I need *all* my classes to implement `Serializable`.

Are there any Netbeans shortcuts that can make this happen to all of them, at once?

Comment: Why don't you write a program that will complete this task for you ? :)

Comment: Fair enough @skomisa.  I should have taken more time to understand the question.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to implement serializable on all your super classes. Anything that inherits will automatically be good to go.

Comment: This does exclude non-inherited classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that there is any such shortcut key in eclipse(Not Sure about the Netbeans). 
However, you can write a utility program which will add `implements Serializable` at the end of the class definition in every .java file in a folder and its subdirectories.